# APA formatting and changing the parameters

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, bibtex, apa-style

So my teacher is being really picky with the APA formatting of my paper and I decided to use LaTeX to typeset my paper (currently its 21 pages). I used the  package \usepackage[man]{apa} which has double spaced it for me, and put a running head on it. I need to move the running head on the title page up an inch or so, and I need to change what it says. I also have to change the spacing on the title page so that my name, school name and project title are all together and not spaced far apart. The other issue is that the \subsection{} command gives me an italicized heading instead of an upright bold face heading. I also have to write the bibliography, but since I have to submit my paper to a number of places (each with its own format) I need to constantly change the format (that's why I dumped MS Word and stuck with a TeX system) and I need to know how to write a bibliography in BibTeX. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE! You raise a whole bunch of issues. On the TeX.SE site, answers tend to be more forthcoming if each posting raises only one question. The more specific you can be about what you're trying to achieve, the greater the likelihood that you'll get some great answers.

Which TeX distribution do you use, by the way, and how up to date is it?

About APA-compliant formatting: You may want to look into using the [apa6](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/apa6) document class; you'd load it with the instruction

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
```

on the first line of your document.

Regarding bibliographies and citations: Since you're apparently fairly new to LaTeX and thus may not have much human capital invested in BibTeX, you may want to use the [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex) and [biblatex-apa](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa) packages. (Biblatex is basically more modern and powerful citation and reference manager, and it has many advantages over BibTeX. For more on biblatex vs bibtex, you may want to check out the question [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/5001) on this site.) However, if you *must* use BibTeX, that wouldn't be the end of the world, for sure. A quick introduction to BibTeX is the 16-page document [BibTeXing](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf).

Comment: I believe I am using MikTeX for Windows XP and I am using the WinEdt 7.0 editor. Do I install the apa6 package under the directory \sw\texmf?

Comment: If you're using MikTeX (version 2.9, right?), the files needed to work with the `apa6` documentclass should either already be loaded or will be loaded for you by MikTeX's autoloader when you try to compile a document that invokes this document class. You can also install it semi-manually by launching the "MikTeX Package Manager" program and instructing it to load the apa6-related documents.+